# ExtJS4 XTemplate: conditionals do not get rendered

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I'm trying to create a simple string using the XTemplate class. The code is like the following:

```
var tpl = new Ext.Template('{name} {[isValid ? "valid" : "invalid"]}');
var msg = tpl.apply({ name: 'A', isValid: true });
```

As a result, I get the following in the `msg` variable:

```
A {[isValid ? "valid" : "invalid"]}
```

Looks like the `{[]}` simply does not get processed. The same thing happens if I use `<tpl if="..."></tpl>` instead: the block is written to the output string as is.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `Ext.Template` and `Ext.XTemplate`.  To use the more advanced functionality, like the conditionals, you need to use `new Ext.XTemplate(...)`.

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot. I was 100% sure that I was using XTemplate, not Template. How could I miss that "X"? )

Comment: We've all made the same mistake :-)  Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.